# Unable to edit posts in the Android app

Tags: support, android-app

I have installed the Stack Overflow app on my Android phone. I have enough  reputation points to edit the post, but in the mobile app, it shows this error message:

> You Don't Have Permission to edit this post.

Am I not allowed to edit posts from the app?

Comment: Are you logged in with your user account?

Comment: Yes, sir, I am logged in and I can add question to my favorite

Comment: [The original announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/) says nothing about editing. It may be the case that suggested edits are not currently supported through the app.