# Suggesting an edit using the SO app

Tags: support, edits, stack-overflow-app

I saw a question I wanted to edit today on he Stack Overflow. When I clicked edit it said

> You do not have permission to edit this post

Wondering what is going on here. I have edited many posts on the desktop website.

This picture is from a different random post but this happens on every post.

[image]

Comment: The API is likely limited in its power to take your edit and place it in the review queue, which would happen since you don't have the privilege to edit everywhere.  Gut is telling me that this is intentional, since it'd be an API limitation.

Comment: [Same thing recently reported for the Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355399/unable-to-edit-posts-in-the-android-app), so must be a limitation of the API. I'm still not sure why anyone uses the app, or why it exists, when there is a mobile version of the site. You can edit to your heart's content there.